# NDK is not generating .so file for Arm v7 library

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm using Android NDK version android-ndk-r9  but my NDK is not generating .so file i.e  does not seem to generate the armeabi-v7a ...

Here is CDT GLOBAL BUILD CONSOLE

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project CustomSqlite ****

D:\software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\android-ndk-r9-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd all 
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteCommon.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteConnection.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteGlobal.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteDebug.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= JNIHelp.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= JniConstants.cpp
"Compile thumb : sqliteX <= sqlite3.c
SharedLibrary  : libsqliteX.so
Install        : libsqliteX.so => libs/armeabi/libsqliteX.so

**** Build Finished ****

**** Build of configuration Default for project CustomSqlite ****

D:\software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\android-ndk-r9-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd all 
Install        : libsqliteX.so => libs/armeabi/libsqliteX.so

**** Build Finished ****
```

so i think .so was generated properly

How can i enable it to compile for **armeabi-v7a**

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use flag `APP_ABI :=` in Application.mk file. You can specify architecture here `APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86`, or even you call use `APP_ABI := all`.

Comment: mate what is different between both "APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86" or "APP_ABI := all"?

Comment: all would let you to build for all arch types ( armebi ,..v7a etc )